# How to make a external harddrive bootable(windows) from ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, 13.04, usb-installation

I am using ubuntu 13.04 on my machine. I have a external hard drive of 500 GB. I want to convert that hard drive to a bootable drive with windows in it. Is there any way i can do that?

Will doing this mean that when i plugin my external drive to my machine, I would be getting option either to load linux or windows?

P.S. I do not want to make partitions on my machine because as it is an official laptop.

Comment: How is external drive connected? Windows is licensed to one machine only and therefore does not configure external drives to be bootable. If seen as an internal drive it may work, but if USB, Windows checks and will not let you install.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to boot the external drive automatically only when the external drive is connected. Just install windows to the external drive and set the external drive or USB (if it connects via USB port) as the first bootloader device in the BIOS settings. When the drive is not connected, the next bootloader device  (internal drive) will automatically boot.

---

Alternatively, (assuming windows is already installed on the external drive), run the following command to create a grub menu entry for windows you can select at boot:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Windows should be detected if the drive is recognized at the time of the update. It does not matter if the drive is mounted or not but if it is not recognized, you may need to mount it first.

> Will doing this mean that when i plugin my external drive to my machine, I would be getting option either to load linux or windows?

Yes, connect the drive before you power on the computer and make sure the internal hard disk is set as the first bootloader device in your BIOS settings and not USB or the external drive. You will have the option to boot Ubuntu or Windows, however, you should also have the option even when the drive is not connected.

Comment: Upvote: in practice as well!  ;-)  (I used to run like this until I ditched Windows Vista permanently!)